# Presentviewcontroller/presentmodelviewcontroller for portrait only

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, landscape-portrait, presentviewcontroller

I present my second VC like this.

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[nav setViewControllers:@[vc] animated:NO];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In that second VC, I write this and that method is also being called.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

However, when I rotate my phone, it change to landscape. May I know how to stop that? In my other views, I need to support for landscape but not for this view. How shall I do?

Comment: `[nav setViewControllers:@[vc] animated:NO];` is not the typical way to present a view controller. Why not just push it instead?

Comment: it is because i need to do that kind of animation (present something over something)